# Erro declaração de objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 function Casa()
    {
      var nome;

      var idade;

      function exibeInformacao()
      {
        console.log("O seu nome e: "+this.nome);
        console.log("Sua idade e: "+this.idade);
      }
    }

    var familia = new Casa();

    familia.exibeInformacao();
```

Comment: Lembre-se que orientação a objetos em javascript é diferente de linguagens como Java. Leia mais [Javascript Orientado a Objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Javascript_orientado_a_objetos)

Answer (score 12):

Alternativa à versão do Mukotoshi, em que todos os objetos desse tipo compartilhariam o método (na versão dele, cada um tem uma cópia do método):

```
function Pessoa(nome, idade){
  this.nome = nome;
  this.idade = idade;
}

Familia.prototype.exibeInformacao = function(){
    console.log("O seu nome e: "+this.nome);
    console.log("Sua idade e: "+this.idade);
};

var pessoa = new Pessoa("Fulano", 30);
pessoa.exibeInformacao();
```

Answer (score 8):

Tente assim:

```
function Casa(){

  this.nome;
  this.idade;

  this.exibeInformacao = function(){
    console.log("O seu nome e: "+this.nome);
    console.log("Sua idade e: "+this.idade);
  };

}

var familia = new Casa();

familia.exibeInformacao();
```

Comment: +1. Só muda o `consel` aí pra `console` ;)

Comment: Verdade, nem tinha visto isso... rsrs